# D3 - Map array to bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and try to implement a simple bar chart with this example:
https://bl.ocks.org/caravinden/d04238c4c9770020ff6867ee92c7dac1

Different to the original I tried to took an array list as data source. Using my code below gives me these console errors:

> Error:  attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".
>
> Error:  attribute height: Expected length, "NaN".

The chart itself is displayed without data.
I know the errors occur when setting y and height in the last few code lines. If I replace y(d.CasesTotal) with numbers it works fine (but makes obviously no sense at all).
Ideas anyone?

```
var svg = d3.select("#barChart"),
    margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);
console.log(y);
let fakeTimeline = [
    {StatDay: "a", CasesTotal: 500},
    {StatDay: "b", CasesTotal: 800}];
    //countryList[0].getFakeTimeLine();

x.domain(fakeTimeline.map(function(d) {return d.StatDay;}));
y.domain(0, d3.max(fakeTimeline, function(d) { console.log(d.CasesTotal);return Number(d.CasesTotal);}));
g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

g.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Fälle");

g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(fakeTimeline)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(d.StatDay);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.CasesTotal);
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return height - y(d.CasesTotal);
    });
```

Comment: The domain of a D3 scale must be an array. Your provide a Y scale domain with `([0,d3.max(...)])` instead of `([0,d3.max(...)])`.

Comment: Ah damn, I didn't recognize this... It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

D3 scale must be an array. So I changed this

```
y.domain(0, d3.max(fakeTimeline, function(d) { console.log(d.CasesTotal);return Number(d.CasesTotal);}));
```

to this

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(fakeTimeline, function(d) { console.log(d.CasesTotal);return Number(d.CasesTotal);})]);
```